# How to effect entities with a potion effect in a certain radius in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So im trying to make a custom potion using an xp bottle, I'm using the command `/execute @e[type=xporb] ~ ~ ~ effect @e[r=5] poison 5 2 true`, I'm trying to make it where anything in a radius of 5 will be poisoned, so is it possible, or did I make a mistake when writing the command?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I failed on the other answer. Here's the correct way:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you execute a command as an entity you have to include a / before the command which is easy to forget as command blocks don't require them. The new command should look like this:

```
/execute @e[type=xporb] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[r=5] poison 5 2 true
```

Comment: This is not and never has been a requirement